# Showing names of levels in glmer R

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding, reporting

I have a simple question that would help me a lot in interpreting my results

I ran  a glmer model in R with the following variables:

1. a binary DV that is dummy coded
2. a categorical IV1 named "condition" with three levels. Contrast coded as (-.66, .33, .33) then as (0, .50, -.50)
3. a categorical IV2 named "prime_type" with two levels contrast coded as -.5,.5
4. a categorical IV3 named "TP_place" with two levels dummy coded

   ```r
   Random effects:
    Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    ID     (Intercept) 2.342    1.530   
    item   (Intercept) 1.100    1.049   
   Number of obs: 1527, groups:  ID, 144; item, 30

   Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
   (Intercept)            -3.02220    0.33679  -8.973  < 2e-16 ***
   condition1              0.01811    0.41729   0.043  0.96539    
   condition2              0.54350    0.46128   1.178  0.23870    
   prime_type1             0.34976    0.48862   0.716  0.47411    
   TP_placeright          -0.16971    0.23943  -0.709  0.47843    
   condition1:prime_type1 -2.00363    0.57737  -3.470  0.00052 ***
   condition2:prime_type1 -0.80298    0.60180  -1.334  0.18210
   ```

```
I want R to show the names of the levels for all categorical variables in the model output. This is because I'm confused as to whether the estimate for condition1 shows the effect for the first or second contrast coding.
```

Comment: You can do this in R with the package `gtsummary`, see example in the duplicate post

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen thank you so much for your reply!